# How to set ng-true-value of a checkbox dynamically when checkboxes are created dynamically in ng-repeat Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have number of checkboxes created using the ng-repeat based on the dynamic data, I want to set the ng-true-value of a checkbox with the dynamic data, that is a string, My code is as Follow:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PostList">
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="ff in totalFeatures">
                <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="checkBoxModel.search[$index]" ng-true-value="{{ff}}" ng-false-value="" name="{{ff}}"/>
                <label>{{ff}}</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define `checkBoxModel.search[$index]` as `ng-model`.

`ng-true-value / ng-false-value` represents the values which are bound to the model on `true` or `false`.

If these values are no `boolean` you have to wrap them with single quote too.

eg. `ng-true-value="'{{ff.checkedTrueValue}}'"`

Answer (score 1):

Try to utilize `ng-repeat` instance like this

```
 <li ng-repeat="ff in totalFeatures">
    <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="ff.isChecked" ng-true-value="{{ff.checkedTrueValue}}" ng-false-value="{{ff.checkedFalseValue}}" />
    <label>{{ff}}</label>
  </li>
```

You can get/set value of `isChecked`,`checkedTrueValue`,`checkedFalseValue` in `$scope.totalFeatures`

Comment: hello, Anik Islam Abhi, I want to set the checkBoxModel.search[$index] with the value {{ff}}, so how can i put the value of {{ff}} in to  checkBoxModel.search[$index] .

Comment: because i get the name of categories in the totalFeatures variable and i want to assign each value to each checkbox true value.